# Android Facebook SDK. Add current user to facebook group

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to show the dialog with asking user to join the group. I have not found a solution through the Graph api.

1. How to add the current logged user to my facebook group?
2. What kind of permissions needs to this feature?
3. What needs to do with my development facebook account?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add users to a group, there is no API for it. It was possible with Game Groups, but they are deprecated and don´t work in new Apps anymore.

Comment: Actually, I think so too. But, how facebook did it on main site? It may perhaps to do the same on the side of the application. But with some extra permission from facebook.

Comment: not everything that is possible on facebook.com is available with an API. in that case, there is just no way, that´s a fact.